# How can I get drive information for a remote Windows XP machine?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, remote

I need to get the manufacturer or at least the model of the hard disk installed on a remote Windows machine (running Windows XP; I'm on a Windows 7 machine). I know that I can use `sysinfo.exe` to see that information, but unfortunately this is available only if I use the GUI.

If I call `sysinfo.exe /s <hostname>` I get just a partial output of what is visible in the GUI version. And the online help doesn't show any command line switch for getting the advanced data.

Is there either a way to get that info using `sysinfo.exe` or another tool or maybe a code snippet that would help me to achieve this?

Comment: First command that springs to mind would be WMIC... maybe something like WMIC /NODE:"<hostname>" LOGICALDISK see what that gives you...

Answer (score 2):

Follow the various answers on our sister site: https://superuser.com/questions/708146/how-to-get-the-hard-drive-serial-number

They offer up a few 3rd party solutions and a few WMIC commands as well as discussing Powershell on XP.

Note that XP is completely EOL'd, so new questions at this point here on ServerFault are likely to fall under the Close Reason:

- Questions should demonstrate reasonable business information technology management practices. **Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault** - see the help center.